# python 3 using multiple or and’s in an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

The code that follows always returns 'orange' I've found other ways to do what I want but I do not understand why this does not work.

```
color1 = input('select first color')
color2 = input('select second color')  
if 'color1' == 'red' or 'yellow' and 'color2' == 'red' or 'yellow':
    print('orange')
else:
    print('something else')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does \`a == b or c or d\` always evaluate to True?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true)

Answer (score 1):

Please look on the condition statement more deeply, better to make it clearer also,

```
if 'color1' == 'red' or 'yellow' and 'color2' == 'red' or 'yellow':
```

We can add parenthesis to make it clearer,

```
if ('color1' == 'red') or ('yellow') and ('color2' == 'red') or ('yellow')
```

If we evaluate one group after another we get,

### Code `('color1' == 'red')`

It will be returning `true` whenever the input is 'red' and `false` if it is not 'red'.

### Code `('yellow')`

No way it evaluate to `false`. Because in python, non-empty string (text) is considered as / evaluated to `true`. More over you did it twice!

... etc (we've got the problem).

I think you mean something like this,

```
if (('color1' == 'red') or ('color1' == 'yellow')) and (('color2' == 'red') or ('color2' == 'yellow')):
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to write your conditional statement the long way. Like `color1 == 'red' or color1 == 'yellow'`, etc. Otherwise, it is interpreted as checking if the string is not an empty string (the part `or 'yellow'`). That's not the case because it's the string 'yellow'. Also, be sure to use the variable name (not 'color1', a string).